# Django deserialization of JSON stored in a model field

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django/Python and currently working on a project with a friend. His android app sends data to me in JSON format that looks like this:

```
"datum_isteka": "2",
"e_mail": "null",
"adress": "null",
"goods": "[
           {\"price\":\"2\",
            \"good\":\"dobro1\",
            \"tax_value\":\"2\",
            \"quantity\":\"pdv %1\"},

           {\"price\":\"3\",
            \"good\":\"dobro 2\",
            \"tax_value\":\"3\",
            \"quantity\":\"pdv %3\"}
          ]",
"taxes": 5,
"order_num": 477456,
"store_user": 2
```

In my models this is stored in one field (the `goods`) and in my view i get this whole `goods` part of this JSON represented like this up here... My question is how do i turn this JSON field `goods` to something that is readable to a user. I'm using DRF for communication with android app.

Model:

```
class Obraz(models.Model):
    datum_isteka = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,
                                    default='', null=True)
    e_mail = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, 
                              default='', null=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    taxes = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='',
                                 null=True)
    goods = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    store_user=models.ForeignKey(Owner, default='Owner')
```

Model serializer:

```
class ObrazSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Obraz
        fields = ('datum_isteka', 'e_mail', 'adress', 'taxes', 
                  'order_num','goods ', 'store_user',)
```

Comment: He's sending you data in a bad format, then. There's no need to convert the `goods` field to a string before serializing it.

Comment: Hmm.. Funny thing is that when I show these `goods` in a view it looks like a normal JSON file. The slashes are gone..

Comment: You should show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [JSONField](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield) on the model

```
class Obraz(models.Model):
    ...
    goods = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

and a [JSONField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield) (notice it's not the same field) on the serializer:

```
class ObrazSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    goods = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = Obraz
        fields = ('datum_isteka', 'e_mail', 'adress', 'taxes', 
                  'order_num','goods', 'store_user',)
```

hope this helps

Comment: btw: this means that you won't need to escape the json in the client side anymore.. the field on the model will convert the JSON to string before storing it in the DB and back to a dict when retrieving the data